# PHP no me reemplaza un caracter en un string

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una consulta con CURL en PHP

```
$handler = curl_init("https://doffice.dexcar.de/api/AdvisorProfile/15ef1274-6ff5-4b3c-87bd-02f9f103fdb9");  
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
$response = curl_exec($handler);  
curl_close($handler);  
$response = substr($response, 0, -1);
$response = str_replace("\"", "'", $response);
print_r(json_decode($response));
```

Esa consulta me devuelve un `json` el cual debo convertir a un array de PHP con `json_decode()`, pero no lo convierte por que retorna el `json` de este modo

```
[{"Id":"15ef1274-6ff5-4b3c-87bd-02f9f103fdb9","Name":"Livio PEDRON","Nickname":"THE_BOSS","Photo":null,"City":"RIVOLI","Address":{"Street":"via Ivrea, 14/E","Zip":"10098","Country":{"Code":"IT","Name":"Italy"}},"Level":"Advisor","Email":"livio@fadgroup.it","Phone":"+39 335 5206976","Rating":0.0,"Zone":"TORINO"}]
```

La idea es convertir la comilla doble (`"`) en comilla simple (`'`) pero por alguna razon, no lo hace.

Comment: Que yo sepa, json_decode tambien acepta comillas dobles

Comment: Si, pero no viene en el formato correcto como para interpretar las comillas doble, si vienen las comillas doble deberia venir como `\"`

Comment: Igualmente, ese no es el problema, el problema es que no logro remplazar en es json la comilla doble por `'` ni tampoco por `\"`

Comment: Intenta con `\\"` o `\\\"`.

Comment: de que manera, puedes ser mas especifico?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto, sustitui todo mi codigo PHP por el siguiente

```
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://doffice.dexcar.de/api/AdvisorProfile/15ef1274-6ff5-4b3c-87bd-02f9f103fdb9"), true);

print_r($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando un header al [**CURL**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) para indicar que la petición te devuelve algo.

> **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**
>
> **TRUE** para devolver el resultado de la transferencia como string del
>   valor de `curl_exec()` en lugar de mostrarlo directamente.

Entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera y sin reemplazar nada en el string.

```
$url = "https://doffice.dexcar.de/api/AdvisorProfile/15ef1274-6ff5-4b3c-87bd-02f9f103fdb9";
$handler = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handler);
curl_close($handler);

print_r(json_decode($response));
```